# replace glue with presto built-in commands

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have completed all the steps mentioned in this tutorial.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/improve-amazon-athena-query-performance-using-aws-glue-data-catalog-partition-indexes/

I am getting the expected results. But I will like to know if this is possible without glue.

I will like to use only Athena (as well as S3) and nothing else to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Athena uses the Glue Data Catalog to store table metadata. Technically you can use Athena Federation to not use the Glue Data Catalog, but for normal usage the Glue Data Catalog is necessary, just like S3 is.

Partition indexes is a feature of Glue Data Catalog, and without implementing something like it yourself and use Federation there is no equivalent feature in Athena itself, since Athena does not store table metadata itself.

Perhaps you could explain in more detail *why* you don't want to use Glue Data Catalog?

Comment: I am always looking for "purist" solution. If athena does not support this then probably presto too does not. I do not want to use it, if glue is doing something "internally" that I can not see nor understand.

Comment: Once I upload new files to S3 will the athena table be able to read them?